# println() method in Java for Strings equality ... and how it works exactly?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to understand the working of System.out.println() in Java... in following 2 code snippet , why the answer is different and why it do not print "Hello: "  string inside println() method ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "abc";
        String y = "abc";
        System.out.println("Hello:" + x == y);
        System.out.println("x.equals(y): " + x.equals(y));

        if(x == y){
            System.out.println("Hello:" + x==y);
        }

}
```

Answer is :

```
false
x.equals(y): true
false
```

And for second code snippet :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "abc";
        String y = "abc";

        System.out.println( x == y);

        System.out.println("x.equals(y): " + x.equals(y));

        if(x == y){
            System.out.println(x==y);
        }

}
```

The answer is:

```
true
x.equals(y): true
true
```

Answer (score 12):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html): `"Hello:" + x == y` is equivalent to `("Hello:" + x) == y`.

Because `+` has a higher precedence than `==`.

Comment: Thanks @assylias....Yes, I got it now...,,Now I put brackets around x==y and it works fine . e.g System.out.println( "Hello: " + (x == y));

Answer (score 2):

first one is returning false because + operator has high precedency than == operator it will also return true if you replace your code
 `System.out.println("Hello:" + (x == y));`

you can also refer for see the difference in == and equals method at here
[What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

because i will also tell the same.

and for operator precedence see this..
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/